# PHP curl CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT has no effect on connection timeout

Tags: php, curl

I have following settings:

```
$handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$response = curl_exec($handle);
```

But when request is sent to server, which is currently not responding at all, curl returns answer in 1 second. I don't understand why that is happening, because I have set CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT to 30, which should mean that curl tires to connect to server 30 seconds. I need curl to try connection for 30 seconds, isn't that what CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT is supposed to do, or is there some kind of misunderstanding?

Here is what print_r(curl_getinfo($handle), true) returns:

```
(
    [url] => http://server.url
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 1.045
    [namelookup_time] => 0.016
    [connect_time] => 0
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [redirect_url] => 
)
```

Comment: `But when request is sent to server, which is currently not responding at all` how can one send a request to a server that is not responding 'at all'? can you tcp connect to the server?

Comment: What kind of answer do you get after that 1 second? Maybe the server denies the request so there is no need to try it again.

Comment: @Mo.sch I tried to reach that url with firefox & firebug net panel, and it says status aborted. I have no idea what that means.

Comment: What does wireshark say? can you try curl on the command line?

Comment: In my opinion this means, that there was a connection which got closed by the remote site (aborted). The server denied your connection so there is no need to wait for anything.
BTW: connection_timeout is a setting to tell curl how long to wait until it stops trying to reach the remote host.

Comment: @Mo.sch post your comment as answer so I can close this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion this means, that there was a connection which got closed by the remote site (aborted). The server denied your connection so there is no need to wait for anything. BTW: connection_timeout is a setting to tell curl how long to wait until it stops trying to reach the remote host. – Mo.sch 13 hours ago